# Finding equipotential surfaces of gravitational field

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential

Consider a point $A$ located in New York city. How to find a point $B$ located in Chicago with the same gravitational potential as $A$? Is there any practical method of doing this? And with what accuracy can this be done?

For two points in an ocean, far from shore we can probably take water surface as the first approximation, and make correction for the tide. But I do not see what can be done on land.

If the points $A$ and $B$ are not far away, say less than a mile, I can connect them with a pipe and fill this pipe with water, the water levels at the ends of the pipe will give me the points of the same potential. But this is not practical for distant points.

EDIT. This question has an important practical application: hitting a small target with a ballistic missile.

Comment: Very accurate scale?

Comment: Very accurate scale will measure $g$ (acceleration of gravity) which is essentially the GRADIENT of the potential. And I want to measure the potential itself, not its gradient.

Comment: In practice you will always measure g. Take any plane of equal g as the zero potential plane of reference.

Comment: If the money was not an object, we could launch pairs of rockets (the ones that do not have air resistance) from different elevation points, toward a common point somewhere far enough in space, about midway between New York and Chicago, and compare fuel consumption at the point of rendezvous.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know how to launch the rockets without air resistance.

Comment: @Gluoncito: Equal g does not imply equal potential. If you climb a stars 10 meters high, the change of g is almost non-detectable while the change in ponential is 10g.

Comment: Of course Alexandre, you are right, but I meant from the experimental point of view you'll measure forces, you don't measure a potential. However, if you look for a model for the gravitational potential of the earth, may be the answer below is a good starting point.

Comment: However, please note that in the example you gave above, in that case the variation of g is neglected over a scale of 10 meters, that doesn't mean that g do not change.

Comment: @Gluoncito: Yes. That's why I also asked "with what accuracy you can measure this potential".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you pose the question in terms of gravity, I think all you need are the spherical harmonic coefficients of a reference geoid.  EGM96 is a commonly used model.  [Here is a link](https://cddis.nasa.gov/926/egm96/getit.html) that will take you to the NASA site where you can download the coefficients.  They go to pretty high order but can be evaluated anywhere, including in the crust, or in space.  [Here are the actual coefficients including standard deviation.](ftp://cddis.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/egm96/general_info/egm96_to360.ascii)  Once you've got this, it's simply a matter varying $(r, \theta, \phi)$ around values in Chicago until you get a match.  Or you could plot counters and do it by eyeball.

**Adding**  a few words about how gravity is measured.  There are gravity meters that you can install at a point and make a measurement of local gravitational acceleration.  Little g.  And gradients of the field.  These can also be used in big G experiments. They make use of some fabulous technology.  [Here is a link to a commercial ultra-precise gravity meter.](http://microglacoste.com/product-category/land/)But for global gravity estimation I don't think anything compares to NASA's Grace Mission (Gravity Recovery And Climate Experiment).  GRACE uses two identical satellites in low-Earth orbit.  By carefully monitoring their relative positions (10 microns over 200 km) changes in the Earth's mass distribution will affect the satellites relative position.  For more details on the physics behind GRACE, [here are links to NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/Grace/spacecraft/index.html) and   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_Recovery_and_Climate_Experiment)

Comment: Thanks. I want to understand HOW this thing can be experimentally MEASURED, I am not looking for the numbers or coefficients.

Comment: Do you mean that you can measure, or that can be measured.  The best gravity measurements in the last decade have been done by the GRACE mission.  https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/Grace/index.html.  This involves twin satellites whose relative distance is measured with phenomenal precision.  They map out gravity through its influence on the satellites' position.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly these satellites measure except the mutual distance, and how they find the gravity potential from these data?

Comment: Here is a link that explains the physics mission far better than I could.  https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/Grace/spacecraft/index.html

Comment: Yes, this answers my question. Please insert this reference in your answer, and I will accept it.